# Recaptcha 3 implementation issue

Tags: javascript, php

Whenever I submit the form the error message I set for an invalid token always fires even though there is a valid token.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=SITE_KEY"></script>
<script>
grecaptcha.ready(function () {
    grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
        var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
        recaptchaResponse.value = token;
    });
});
```

Hidden field in form:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
```

I am serialising the whole form:

```
var form = $('#supportForm').serialize();
```

If I console.log that I can see the token so no problem there.

Ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'validate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form,
       //
```

PHP

```
$recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptcha_secret = 'SECRET_KEY';

$recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $_POST['recaptcha_response']);
$recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);


  if(!$recaptcha->success) {
        $message .= "'Robot verification passed, please try again";
   }
```

I don't know if it is failing because in my google account I set the domain as mydomain.com but the form is actually at mydomain.com/subdirectory

I was not able to add the subdirectory when setting up the captcha.

Comment: Can you see what the full recaptcha response says? Usually that would mention if your domain in recaptcha is set up wrong.

Comment: It shows null in console. But if I alert the form out I can see that the hidden captcha field has a long value. Is there any issue with the Ajax? (added to original question)

Comment: Also, if I console.log the response before using json_decode on it I get 'false'

Comment: Are you sure `file_get_contents` is working? You might need to enable allow_url_fopen in your php.ini

Comment: Ah, how can I test file_get_conents is working if I don't have access to php.ini?

Comment: I believe you should be able to set that option on or off in the PHP settings of your webhosting control panel.

Comment: Would I be able to see like this? I have added `phpinfo();` to a php file and can see a lot of info that way.

Comment: If I search for file_get_conents I don't see it anywhere

Comment: You need to search for `allow_url_fopen` in your php settings not file_get_contents since that is the actual function and not a PHP setting.

Comment: Brilliant, that solved my issue. I turned that on and now it's working. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to enable `allow_url_fopen` in your PHP settings for `file_get_contents` to work.